# How to get the References section to be numbered as if it were created via \section

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, numbering

I am using the bibtex library to reference. Everything works fine but ideally I would like the reference section generated by bibtex to have the ordered number like   \section{} generates.

For example,

```
\section{abstract}
\section{Intro}
\section{conclusion}
\section{reference}
```

would give a the labels 1,2,3,4 but I am using bibtex to generate the reference section:

```
 \section{abstract}
 \section{Intro}
 \section{conclusion}
 \bibliography{my_.bib_file_name}
```

This generates labels 1,2,3 but not the next number. Please let me know if there is a nice way to do this, thanks!

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem with \addcontentsline is that there is not an ordered number next to the entry in the TOC. @egreg i am using article as my document class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `tocbibind` package can help you there. The option `numbib` will make the references into a ordinary section in the `article` class.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\section{Abstract}
\section{Intro}
\section{Conclusion}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice! I found another way to do it also but do not understand how it is working. The code is shown here: \renewcommand{\refname}{\section{References}}. Thanks for everyone help!

Comment: @u-will-neva-no I recommend against that: `\refname` is the title that shall be used for the references, and if no other language is used, this will be, well, References. Squeezing a `\section` into it will produce a a new section whereever this title for the references is used, and that is something quite undersirable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it by hand (no package needed):

```
\stepcounter{section} % Increase counter (section) by one step
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection \quad Bibliography} % Add to ToC (at the section level)
```